# Подскажите как убрать обводку браузера?

Tags: css, ссылки, браузер

[image]
Вот так почему-то отображается после нажатия на ссылку, как убрать?

Comment: Нужны точная версия браузера и работающий пример, а то по-быстрому воспроизвести проблему не получилось

Comment: эти ссылки - по клику по ним всплывает попап?

Comment: А версию браузера всё равно укажите, а то в таком виде вопрос будет малополезен для других

Comment: он выдавал в разных и в хроме и в firefox эту обводку... в других я просто не смотрел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь в свои стили:

```
a {outline:none;}
```